# How to automate the verify, repair and upgrade activity in ALM QC upgrade

Tags: upgrade, verify, alm, hp-quality-center, repair

I am currently taking care of ALM QC upgrade activity from 11 to 12.20.
During this i need to verify, repair and upgrade each project.
Is there any way to automate this?
I am open on using UFT or selenium.
Let me know if there is any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using HP ALM Robot for auto upgrading QC projects. At the time there wasnt much documentation apart from: https://community.softwaregrp.com/dcvta86296/attachments/dcvta86296/itrc-895/91467/1/Robot_User_Guide_0.pdf

Now there are videos to help out the process too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-McyxeW0aI

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `SaApi`. You can read more about it in
  `ALM help-> API references -> HP ALM Site Administration API Reference`

Basically it's a dll that is a COM object, so you can register it by `regsvr32` and use it in your .NET application or vbs application.

To get this dll just login to site admin once - and you'll have it along with other site admin libraries in a path like this ->
 `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\HP\ALM-Client\YOUR_ALM_NAME`

```
run cmd.exe as Administrator  
register SAClient.dll in cmd  
-> C:\Windows\system32>regsvr32 C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\HP\ALM-Client\YOUR_ALM_NAME\SAClient.dll
```

Now you can add `SAClient` to your project references.

[image: references]

Create a simple client.

```
public class ALMSiteAdminClient
{
private SAapi sconnection = new SAapi();

public void connect(string url, string user, string password)
{
  sconnection.Login(url, user, password);
}

public void disconnect()
{
  sconnection.Logout();
}

public void verifyProject(string domain, string project)
{
  sconnection.Verify(domain, project, "basic");
}
public void repairProject(string domain, string project)
{
  sconnection.Repair(domain, project, "");
}
public void upgradeProject(string domain, string project)
{
  sconnection.Upgrade(domain, project, "");
}}
```

Use the client ;)

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
  //get list of a projects from anywhere you want
  //this is just a mock example
  Dictionary<string, string> projects = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  projects.Add("domain1", "project1");
  projects.Add("domain1", "project2");

  //create site admin client and login
  ALMSiteAdminClient SACLIENT = new ALMSiteAdminClient();
  SACLIENT.connect("http://myd-vm15059.hpeswlab.net:8081/qcbin", "sa","");
  //do whatever you need with each project
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> project in projects)
  {
    SACLIENT.verifyProject(project.Key, project.Value);
    SACLIENT.repairProject(project.Key, project.Value);
    SACLIENT.upgradeProject(project.Key, project.Value);
  }
  //logout
  SACLIENT.disconnect();
}}
```